# Populate Pandas Dataframe column from other columns based on a condition and previous row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have following [Pinescript](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html) statements that I'm trying to implement using python dataframes.

```
Hlv = float(na)
Hlv := close > sma_high ? 1 : close < sma_low ? -1 : Hlv[1]
```

Line 1 - Hlv - is basically a variable name which is a float

Line 2 - Assinging new value to variable , ternary operator (if-elseif-else). The assignment `Hlv[1]` means previous value (value of `Hlv`, 1 step(row) back)

Now Implementing this in Dataframe having following columns and data ->

```
Current ->

Close SMA_High SMA_Low 
 10      12      5
 12      14      6
 13      17      7
```

Now , I want to add another column called HLV storing Hlv values for each row , based on the condition we will compute as in pinescript line2.

```
Expected ->

Close SMA_High SMA_Low  Hlv
 10      9       5       1     // close > sma_high = 1
 5       14      6       -1    // close < sma_low = -1
 13      17      7       -1    // here no conditions are met , so previous value of Hlv is taken i.e -1
```

I am not able to figure out how to generate this new column with values deriving from other columns and even how to take previous value of the column.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66403045/generating-a-pandas-dataframe-column-from-logic-operations-between-other-columns) answer and could see we could add values on condition as below -

```
df['Hlv'] = pd.NA
df.loc[df.Close>df.SMA_High,'Hlv'] = 1
df.loc[df.Close<df.SMA_Low,'Hlv'] = -1
```

But still not sure **how can I populate with previous value if no conditions are met / default case** .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
df['Hlv'] = np.NaN
df.loc[df.Close>df.SMA_High,'Hlv'] = 1
df.loc[df.Close<df.SMA_Low,'Hlv'] = -1
df.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

Comment: how to update with previous row value when no conditions are met ? or default case value

Comment: `df.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)` will fill value with previous one as initially we assign `np.NAN` to whole column

Comment: for more detail refer this link https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html